# Order of $\mathbb{Z}^n/p\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I was given the following question: Let $p$ be prime number, and $n$ natural number. I need to calculate the order of $\mathbb{Z}^n/p\mathbb{Z}^n$.

I think the answer is $p^n$, but I didn't use the fact that $p$ is prime.
So, is my answer correct, and is it correct for every $p$ ?

Comment: Yes it's correct (note spelling!) and it does not depend on $p$ being prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. First, notice that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ has $p^n$ elements. Then use the first isomorphism theorem to show that $\mathbb{Z}^n/p\mathbb{Z}^n$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ to obtain the answer.